# Why am I failing?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Oh no! I just got my grades back and it seems that I am failing my math class. I thought I had been doing okay, but maybe I wasn't. I think that there is something wrong with my grades. Can you help me figure out what's wrong, and what my actual grade should be?

> Lesson 1: 12/1675
> Lesson 2: 41/4591
> Lesson 3: 23/2785
> Practice Test: 9/1182
> Test 1: 37/4093

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing ok actually,

> The marks report is missing some spacing and the final percent sign

Let's see if I can fix it for you:

> Lesson 1: 12/16 75%
> Lesson 2: 41/45 91%
> Lesson 3: 23/27 85%
> Practice Test: 9/11 82%
> Test 1: 37/40 93%